# Logger working in one file but in another

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I have my package structures defined as follows for a dependency named `MyProject`which is used in another maven project:

[image]

In the  `application.properties` file, I have the level for loggers on classes inside the root package defined as follows:

```
logging.level.abc.xyz.registry=DEBUG
env=DEV
email_to=myname@example.com
```

I have some `logger.info("Test")`defined in the following file and I can see them printing on the console.

```
Myproject/src/main/java/abc/xyz/registry/orm/dao/impl/File1DaoImpl.java
```

I have some `logger.info("Test")` and `logger.debug("Test")` defined in the following file as well. However,I cannot see the logger printing any information on the console :

```
Myproject/src/main/java/abc/xyz/registry/orm/dao/impl/File2DaoImpl.java
```

Any reason why this is happening?

Logger Declarations in both the classes :

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(File1DaoImpl.class);

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(File2DaoImpl.class);
```

`File1DaoImpl` has logger defined in the following manner(Basically I am not printing any variables here and just messages)

```
logger.info("Starting Insert method in Eclipse May 22 File1DaoImpl.insert() .....");
```

I have it defined like the following in `File2DaoImpl` which doesn't works:

```
logger.debug("Records Updated in File2DaoImpl params : " + 
                     "employeeId:"+employeeId+
                     ",tokenID:"+tokenID+
                     ",newEmpID:"+newEmpID+
                     ",userComments="+userComments
                     ); 



logger.info("INSERTED Records from the File2DaoImpl:"+
                              "employeeId:"+employeeId+
                              ",tokenID:"+tokenID+
                              ",newEmpID:"+newEmpID+
                              ",userComments="+userComments
                             );
```

I have following import statements in both the classes:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

Comment: Can you add how are the logger variables declared in both classes?

Comment: @Pablo Please find my updated post. Thanks

Comment: Updated the actual logger declarations for both the classes

Comment: Are you sure your `logger.info` statement is reached, no if or...?

Comment: @RC That file is doing it's job and updating the database, so I am assuming the control is going through those `logger.info` statement. How can I check if it's reaching there or not? Thanks

Comment: debug it, or add some `System.out.println` output or something similar

Comment: Hmm , `System.out.println` doesn't seem like printing anything.